# Migrating Remote Desktop 2008 Users to RD 2008 R2

Tags: remote, service, desktop

I have created a new server 2008 R2 remote desktop env and would like to know how to move several users over from old 2008 remote desktop env.

Also is it possible to setup group policy for locking down the RDP enviroment, and not the users own enviroment using the same login etc as the servers for RDP are on the same domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[USMT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560801%28WS.10%29.aspx) will migrate the user profiles.

Yes, GPO can be applied to RDP Environments; GPOs can be applied to various different objects in AD. You're probably looking to do User Settings on a policy assigned to the Machine Account's AD Contains, in which case you'll need to enable [Loopback Processing](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231287).